# "not a well-formed equation" using Mathematica Eliminate

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Using the Eliminate function, I am getting an error stating "Eliminate::eqf: y is not a well-formed equation"

```
Symbol["a"];
Symbol["b"];
Symbol["s"];
Symbol["x0"];
Symbol["y0"];

x == (a/(2*s))*
   Sqrt[2 + 2*s*Sqrt[2]*cos[t] + s^2*cos[2*t]] - (a/(2*s))*
   Sqrt[2 - 2*s*Sqrt[2]*cos[t] + s^2*cos[2*t]] + x0

y == (b/(2*s))*
   Sqrt[2 + 2*s*Sqrt[2]*sin[t] - s^2*cos[2*t]] - (b/(2*s))*
   Sqrt[2 - 2*s*Sqrt[2]*sin[t] - s^2*cos[2*t]] + y0

Eliminate[{x, y}, t]
```

What determines a well-formed solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mathematica is case sensitive and uses `Cos[t]` and `Sin[t]`, not cos[t] or sin[t]. `Eliminate` expects to be given equations.

Try this

```
Eliminate[{
  x == (a/(2*s))*Sqrt[2 + 2*s*Sqrt[2]*Cos[t] + s^2*Cos[2*t]] - (a/(2*s))*Sqrt[2 - 
    2*s*Sqrt[2]*Cos[t] + s^2*Cos[2*t]] + x0,
  y == (b/(2*s))*Sqrt[2 + 2*s*Sqrt[2]*Sin[t] - s^2*Cos[2*t]] - (b/(2*s))*Sqrt[2 - 
    2*s*Sqrt[2]*Sin[t] - s^2*Cos[2*t]] + y0},t]
```

which gives a partial solution, but your problem is sufficiently complicated that it does not completely solve for t and it warns that it has used inverse functions in what it did which might have missed some potential solutions.

This

```
Reduce[{
  x == (a/(2*s))*Sqrt[2 + 2*s*Sqrt[2]*Cos[t] + s^2*Cos[2*t]] - (a/(2*s))*Sqrt[2 - 
    2*s*Sqrt[2]*Cos[t] + s^2*Cos[2*t]] + x0,
  y == (b/(2*s))*Sqrt[2 + 2*s*Sqrt[2]*Sin[t] - s^2*Cos[2*t]] - (b/(2*s))*Sqrt[2 - 
    2*s*Sqrt[2]*Sin[t] - s^2*Cos[2*t]] + y0},t]
```

may or may not give a more detailed and complicated result which should correctly handle the inverse function special cases and that you may or may not be able to apply to your problem.